# Where I can find data to test my CSP Map coloring solver

Tags: maps, artificial-intelligence, constraint-programming

I write CSP map coloring problem solver. A definied constraint as Constraint(A, B) what means that country A is adjacent to country B. Currently I create maps by hand but now I need some big map to test my algorithm. Do you know where I can find some easy to parse data?
Something like this would be ideal for me:

```
A B
B C
A D
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some nice example graphs of various kinds available from Donald Knuths [Stanford GraphBase page](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/sgb.html).